# how to parse Zero (0) as integer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parseint

I am working on a basic calculator that takes input like this
    `" 100 + 10/2 + 3 + 0 "` and returns the output in a separate field.
when I break this thing into an array zero is not parsed as integer. My code is as following

```js
var arr = ["100", "+", "0"];
arr = arr.map(x => parseInt(x) || x);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Zero is a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), so short-circuiting won't work here. You need to check explicitly

```js
var arr = ["100", "+","0"];
arr = arr.map( x => x == 0 ? 0 : (parseInt(x) || x));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 6):

It's because `0` is falsy so after the `parseInt("0")` returns falsy  you end up getting the string

Try using [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) instead

```js
var arr = ["100", "+","0"];
arr = arr.map( x => isNaN(x) ? x : parseInt(x) );

// use F12 to see the console
console.log(arr); // output is being display as [100, "+","0"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to other answers, zero is falsey. However, `parseInt` [returns NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) upon failure, and that can be used to build the answer as follows:

```js
let arr = ["100", "+", "0"];
arr = arr.map((x) => {
  const parsed = parseInt(x);
  return Number.isNaN(parsed) ? x : parsed;
});
console.log(arr);
```

IMO this is a better solution as it is explicit about the return types that parseInt returns, and doesn't rely on type coercion.

Note: There are fun nuances with isNaN. The [ES2015 Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) is used here to prevent any issues with type coercion, although it's not strictly necessary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt("0")` is falsy. You can use `Number()` to convert 0 to an integer.

Try the following:

```js
var arr = ["100", "+", "0"];
arr = arr.map(x => !isNaN(Number(x))? Number(x) : x);

console.log(arr);
```